Conway Exercise 12 A course in operator theory
The following is an exercise 12 (Page 71) from Conway’s book “A course in operator theory”. I have solved the first part for the following question by considering the Gelfand’s map on the space of continuous functions on the joint spectrum of $(N_1, \dotsc, N_p)$ and obtain a unique spectral measure $E$. The idea is same as discussed here in Spectral measure for a finite set of mutually commuting normal operators .
My question is how does one recapture the spectral measure for each $N_k$ from the spectral measure $E$ as asked in the exercise.

